# Displaying a model associated with a separate controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I have a model `WebsiteTemplate` that belongs to a `WebLayout`. In the UI I want to display a list of all of the `webLayouts` but be able to have an html class added to the one whose id is the same as `webLayout`'s. `webLayout` belongs to `websiteTemplate`, which is the model for the route we are visiting.

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm aware that I could have something just fundamentally wrong with my setup as well, so thoughts on that are welcome. It seems like I'd want to pass in another parameter to `render` with the specific `webLayout`, but this doesn't seem to be the Ember way.

```
# website_template model
App.WebsiteTemplate = DS.Model.extend
 webLayout: DS.belongsTo("App.WebLayout")

# website_layout model
App.WebLayout = DS.Model.extend
 name: DS.attr("string"),
 thumbnail: DS.attr("string")

# router
App.Router.map ->
 @resource "website_template", path: "/website_template/:website_template_id"

# website_template route
App.WebsiteTemplateRoute = Ember.Route.extend
 setupController: ->
 @controller.set 'webLayouts',  App.WebLayout.find()

# website_template template
{{webLayout.id}}
{{render "_webLayouts" webLayouts}}

# web_layouts template
<ul>
 {{#each controller}}
  <li>
   <a href="#" {{ action "addLayout" this }}>
    <img alt="Thumbnail" {{ bindAttr src="thumbnail" }}>
    {{ name }}
   </a>
  </li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I know the following *doesn't* work, but here's pseudo-code of the idea I'm trying to accomplish.

```
# website_template template
{{render "_webLayouts" webLayouts webLayout}}

# web_layouts template
<ul>
 {{#each webLayouts in controller}}
   {{#if webLayouts.id is webLayout.id}}
    <li class="selected">
   {{else}}
    <li>
   {{/end}}
    <a href="#" {{ action "addLayout" this }}>
    <img alt="Thumbnail" {{ bindAttr src="thumbnail" }}>
    {{ name }}
   </a>
  </li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show the definition of your `WebLayout` model?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I edited the question with the `WebLayout` model. There's no associations in it currently.

Comment: when you use `belongsTo` to declare a one-to-one relationship between two models I guess there should be and association...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first look what I see is missing is the correct setup of an one-to-one relation between two models.

Example:

```
# website_template model
App.WebsiteTemplate = DS.Model.extend
  webLayout: DS.belongsTo("App.WebLayout")

# website_layout model
App.WebLayout = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  thumbnail: DS.attr("string"),
  websiteTemplate: DS.belongsTo("App.WebsiteTemplate")
```

As for the comparison of the id's you could write a custom handlebars helper which would basically look like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('equal', function(value1, value2, options) {
  if (value1 === value2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

and then use it like this:

```
{{#equal webLayouts.id webLayout.id}}
  are equal
{{else}}
  not equal
{{/equal}}
```

See here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/inokim/2/edit) for the custom helper.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @JessicaDillon do you mean that you have cases where you don't have a `webLayout.id` to pass to the `equal` helper?